# How to append a variable value in a new line of a existing file in unix(.ksh)?

Tags: unix

I have a file called test.txt.

I already have a value in test.txt file is,

abcdefghijklmnopqrst

123456789101112113

How do I append another value taken from a variable, into this file's 3rd row/line?

For example, I wanted to get a value called 'asdadasdadadadasdasdasdasdasd' from a variable called 'base', and append this value to the test.txt file (in 3rd line), so that it has the file should be like,

abcdefghijklmnopqrst

123456789101112113

asdadasdadadadasdasdasdasdasd 
in it.

Appreciate all your help!

Thanks

Comment: `echo "$base" >> test.txt`

Comment: shall it append from the 3rd line?

Comment: yes, it'll append `>>` the value stored in variable `base` to the 3rd line.Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: It is working. Thank You so much.